# Remove a part of the URL using REGEX and .htacess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to replace this URL:

```
mydomain.com/posts/1659-artigos/etc-to
```

By this one:

```
mydomain.com/etc-to
```

Using .htaccess I'm trying the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^posts/1659-artigos/(.*)$ $1
```

But it isn't working. No redirect happens.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^posts/1659-artigos/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]` should work

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks a lot! Write it in the answer!

Comment: @anubhava maybe you could also look into this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68672253/replace-part-of-the-url-and-add-two-zeros-in-string-with-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You can use this code to get redirect working:

```sh
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^posts/1659-artigos/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

You need to use `/` before `$1` for external redirect and make sure to use `R` flag for full redirect.