# Replace part of the URL and add two zeros in string with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone help me with this regular expression so I can replace:

This URL:

```
mydomain.com/artigos/8170-comooool
```

To:

```
mydomain.com/blog/817000-comooool
```

This is:

```
1: Replace the word `artigos` by `blog`
2: Add two zeros to the 4 digit number after the slash
```

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^artigos(\d{4}-.*) /blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please show your current .htaccess in question

Comment: @anubhava I'm trying a lot of stuff like: RewriteRule ^artigos(\d{4}-.*) /blog/$1 [R=301,L]  - but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this redirect rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^artigos/(\d+)(-.*)$ /blog/$100$2 [L,R=301,NE,NC]
```

We have to use 2 separate capture groups: 1st to capture all digits after `/artigos/` and 2nd to capture all text beyond that.

Comment: YES! You got it again! How did you learn so much about this? I find it really tough!

Comment: Most of this is regular expressions and then some technical details of `mod_rewrite`